# Should I worry about a refreshed job posting?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

**I got the job** at an insurance firm.

It's a matter of time before I officially start.

The contract signature is conditioned with poviding evidences of what is claimed on my resume.

I handed them my documents (diplomas, previous work experience etc.), and I was told if I could start next week rather than next month.

After a short discussion, we established that it's better to start next month (relocating etc.).

I was surprised to see that this company refreshed the job posting a little after I hand them these documents.

Was it a coincidence or should I worry?

Comment: You either have the job or you don't, [relisting a job posting means nothing](http://www.askamanager.org/2010/08/what-does-it-mean-that-job-i.html).

Comment: How big is the company? re-posting the exact same job when there are X hundred people working in that building in a company with Y thousand people means nothing.

Comment: There are still plenty of ways to lose the conditional offer (so it's generally a bad idea to put all your eggs in this basket), but them refreshing the job post doesn't mean much - wait until they actually tell you something before making assumptions.

Comment: @gnat I don't think that post is really the same, OP appears to already have a signed offer from them, the linked post is more about what to do prior to receiving an offer (although that's not to say I think the question should remain open).

Comment: It could be that (a) more than one opening existed in the team (or in multiple teams) for this position classification.  (b) This is actually a new opening not related to your offered position.  (c) there is a company policy to continue the advertisements until the position has been filled and started.  Many delayed start offers end up being used to leverage current employers, rather than actually being started.  So its not an unreasonable position to keep searching for available candidates.  This does not mean they do not want you .

Answer (score 5):

Obviously we can't say for sure what they are thinking and there could be various reasons for this:

1. Simple mistake

A breakdown in communication internally has caused the posting to get relisted despite it being filled. Or the instructions to re-list were given before you were hired.

2. Playing it safe

You haven't actually started yet so they could be hedging their bets in case something goes awry between now and you starting the job, you stated that they were checking various things on your resume and also that you were relocating. Both of these things add an element of uncertainty for them so having the relisted posting gives them an easy plan B if it goes wrong.

3. Multiple positions

Is it possible that they actually have multiple openings for that role and haven't filled them all yet?

4. They are planning to ditch you

This is the worst case scenario but one that I feel is also perhaps the least likely.

On the whole I wouldn't overly worry about it - for peace of mind you could always get in touch with them and just confirm that everything is still progressing as expected from their side. This wouldn't be unusual given you are relocating etc and you don't even have to mention the listing if you'd prefer not to.

Comment: 5. The company is willing to create an opening if a sufficiently impressive candidate comes along and can always say no to everyone else. ~~~ 6. The company burns through staff so quickly they need a constant influx of applicants.